# How to get event.target/event.currentTarget for HTML-5 canvas for click handler

Tags: javascript, events, actionscript, html5-canvas

I hope everyone is doing great.

I belong to Actionscript background and just started on Flash CC HTML-5 canvas. How to get `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` in Flash CC for HTML-5 canvas for click event.

Like we used to do it in AS 3.0:

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , go);
function go(evt:MouseEvent) {
    trace(" evt - "+evt.currentTarget); // It will let us know the clicked target
}
```

For HTML-5

```
btn.addEventListener('click' , go.bind(this));
function go(evt){
   console.log(" evt - "+evt.????t); // what is the correct syntax here?
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `evt.target`.

Also see other possibilities below:

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(e) {console.log(e);});
```

```html
<div>F12, then click here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ken for quick reply.
But "evt. originalTarget" is not working, it give undefined. 
Only "evt.target" is working.

Comment: @VarunSoni let me update (works in FF, but I didn't check the other browsers)

Comment: I am working on Mac, it is working on Safari, Chrome and FF. Also worked on IE 9, tested on windows as well.